# Trouble accessing scope attribute in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to access the values in $scope.photoRes in my directive but as of right now the console.log(scope.photoRes) in the directive just shows an empty object.
Output from the console:

```
Object {fileName: "db372ec33603208781eb6fbf9789c816a4ab27d2.jpg", filePath: "C:\wamp\www\skittlize\photo_assets\uploads\db372ec33603208781eb6fbf9789c816a4ab27d2.jpg"} SkittlesCtrl.js:17
Object {} SkittlesCtrl.js:37

'use strict';

angular.module('skittlesApp')
  .controller('SkittlesCtrl', function ($scope, $location){
    $scope.photoRes = {};
    $scope.dropzoneConfig = {
      'options': { // passed into the Dropzone constructor
        'url': 'photo_assets/save2.php'
      },
      'eventHandlers': {
        'sending': function (file, xhr, formData) {
        },
        'success': function (file, response) {
          $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.photoRes = JSON.parse(file.xhr.getResponseHeader("photoInfo"));
            $location.path('/uploader')
            console.log($scope.photoRes);
          });
        }
      }
    };
  })
  .directive('dropzone', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var config, dropzone;   
      config = scope[attrs.dropzone];   
      dropzone = new Dropzone(element[0], config.options);   
      _.each(config.eventHandlers, function (handler, event) {
        dropzone.on(event, handler);
      });
    };
  })
  .directive('imgSwitch', ['PhotoServ', function (PhotoServ) {
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch('photoRes', function (newVal) {
        if (newVal) {
          console.log(scope.photoRes);
          var cropper = new CROP();
          cropper.init('.selfie-container');
          cropper.loadImg('/uploads/'+scope.photoRes.fileName);
          $('.cropButton').on('click', function () {
            PhotoServ.skittlize('/uploads/'+scope.photoRes.fileName);
          });
        }
      });
    };
    return {
      link: link
    }
  }]);
```

Is this happening because my change in the parent scope isn't registering?

Comment: It seems it's just because you're not assigning things to scope of the directive.

Comment: How do you use directives in html?

Comment: @YanisT, is that a new question that you're asking? You should probably post it as such, not as a comment piggybacking on someone else's question.
You can also turn to the Docs or other Angular tutorials for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt `scope[attrs.dropzone]` is valid. I don't see anywhere where you're assigning `scope` within the directive.

There are 2 different ways to solve this. One is to just pass it as an attribute (which you may already be doing, but I don't know what your HTML looks like).

```
<div dropzone photoRes="{{photoRes}}"> </div>
```

Then you can just call `attrs.photoRes` to get the value.

The other option is to assign scope within the directive. You'd use `@`, `=`, or `&` Most likely `@` would be acceptable for you. If I remember correctly, `@` takes the value from an attribute. So you'd still need to pass in your `$scope` as an attribute.

`=` on the other hand would bind with a `$scope` object, and create a 2-way data binding. Which you probably don't need here.

```
.directive('dropzone', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            photoRes: "@",

        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs ) {
            console.log(attrs.photoRes);
            console.log(scope.photoRes);

    };
})
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify the issue is actually accessing from inside the `imgSwitch` directive

Comment: I assume that is your own directive?
If that's the case, you need to post that in your original question. That changes the question quite a bit.
And you should probably create a JSFiddle or Plunker to demonstrate your issue then.